# Fix 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'could_extract_minus_sign'

Tags: python-3.x

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y')
C = symbols('C')

# y' + 2/x (y) = sin(x) 

Intfact = exp((integrate(2/x,x)))
print(Intfact)
Zsoln = ((integrate((sin(x)/x)*Intfact,x)+C)/Intfact)
print('y(x) =', Zsoln.expand()) 

x = np.array(range(0,100))
y = (-2/x**2) - (cos(x)/x) + (sin(x)/x**2)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

error is in 'y = (-2/x**2) - (cos(x)/x) + (sin(x)/x**2)' 
I need to plot this euqation where C is equal to [-2,-1,0,1,2]
how do I resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can write this like this:

`y = (np.divide(-1, np.power(x, 2))) - (np.divide(np.cos(x), x)) + (np.divide(np.sin(x), np.power(x, 2)))`